# Sitefinity PageControl QueryString values

Tags: request.querystring, sitefinity-4

We're upgrading a project from Sitefinity 3.7 to 4.4 and some of our controls need to be updated. Apparently we now have to have our UserControls inherit from PageControl, but when you do that there's no access to the QueryString values.

Anyone know what's going on or how to get around it?

I know we could potentially use the HttpContext, but I'm stumped as to why Telerik would have hidden these values.

Thanks,
jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to widgets, they can still be developed as UserControls (.ascx files). There is an introduction to widget development here: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/gabesumner/posts/11-08-29/ldquo_hello_world_rdquo_guide_to_custom_sitefinity_widgets_amp_controldesigners.aspx

But you can absolutely use a UserControl which would give you full acess to the HttpContext.

I hope this is helpful!